# How to create an algorithm for mapping two values into one

Tags: algorithm

I have a sorted sequence of about 200 elements. The value *"rank"* with double type stores place of element in this sequence. If I change place of element in the collection, then *rank* also changed. Element also has boolean field of *"priority"* and it can be changed too. So I need to map these *"rank"* and *"priority"* fields into one *"result"* field. It should be something like sorting on 2 columns - at first sort by *priority* and second by *rank*. And I want to get brief value of *result*, for example from 1 to 1000. 
The issue is in range on *rank*. It may be almost any value from double type. So 10 or 1000000000 is correct values for this field. Therefore, I can't simply use "weight" coefficients to  increase *"result"* for priority items. Also since I want to get short value as result, I don't want to get hundred of billions value. I want to get values that easily comparable by humans.

And one more restriction. I want to limit *result* field recalculation as much as possible. In ideal case if I change *rank* or *priority* for one element, then *result* value changed only for this element. I don't want to recalculate *result* values for all elements after one change.

These restrictions can be relaxed, for example it's ok to get *result* value in range from 1 to 10000, but at first I want to get outcome as much as possible to ideal.
I believe it something alike to creation hash function, but I need a human read result of this function and I doubt, that something  similar exist.

***Example***:
At first a have 4 elements with *rank* and *priority* and then I get sorted collection of these elements with *result* value.
A=(10, 0), B=(100,1), C=(1000,0), D=(10000, 1) => B=1, D=2, A=3, C=4.

If I change *priority* for D, then D=(10000, 0) and outcome collection will be:
B=1, A=2, C=3, D=4.

So I don't want to use simple indexes like 1, 2, 3, 4, since in this case I need to recalculate *result* value for 3 elements.

If I may have *result* like B=1, D=5, A=10, C=15, then if I change *result* of D to, for example, 20, then I will need to change *result* only for one element.

Comment: As you write, you would like to have _something like sorting on 2 columns_ - have you considered actual [lexicographic ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order)? If so, do you _really_ need a single numerical value as the outcome?

Comment: Why is rank double? Is it solely calculated from the position of the element, or can it arbitrary set elsewhere?

Comment: @Martheen, alas it's restrictions of another system, which stores rank as double.

Comment: Can you provide (short) examples of input and desired output? Can you not achieve the desired result with a spreadsheet sorting on one column and then on the other, and taking the order of rows as `result`?

Comment: @Codor, a single values is a requirement from customer.

Comment: Can you tell us what programming language you are using, so we know what options you have.

Comment: @AndreyPopov Thanks for the clarification, however the requirement seems nonsensical to me. That being said, I understand that some dynamic behaviour is demanded in the sense that the desired _result_ value does not depend on the actual _range_ of the data, is that correct?

Comment: You could encode the `priority` boolean into the `result` by making the result negative. For instance: `result = priority ? rank - 1000000000 : rank`. And decoding the priority from it: `priority = result < 0`, and the rank: `rank = rank < 0 ? result + 1000000000 : result`

Comment: @tucuxi I added example and desired behavior. So I need something like *sparse* sequence in result

Comment: @capalasavo for this task I want to use Python, but potentially may use JavaScript or C#, if I found more appropriate libs for them.

Comment: @trincot, yes. Thank you for advice. Another solution will be use lexicographical ordering of 2 values. It's ok, but at first I want try to get more short *result* value and in case of real issues choose one of these solution.

Comment: Did you hope to make result shorter than the largest possible value of rank or even the lexicographical order of the tuples? Then you need to look into compression techniques, but that of course comes with a performance cost.

Comment: I somehow misread the question and overlooked the _bool_-ness of priority. I consider trincot's comment to be the anctual answer.

Comment: You can replace `1000000000` by `max(rank) - min(rank)` if you want something more dynamic.

Comment: @trincot, ok, thank you. I will take a look at compression techniques, performance is not a restriction in my case. If I get *result* in a second or ten seconds is not a problem. The issue is to have a human readable value as a result of compression.

Comment: @Stef in general case max(rank)=1000000000, min(rank)=100, so I will not get much profit from this operation.